# How to generate these lists of True and False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am looping through a list of 3 items, something like:

```
for i in range(3):
```

and trying to produce the following lists on each respective iteration:

```
[True, True, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, True, True, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

What would be a good way in python to do this?

Comment: "most efficient" is not a well defined concept.

Comment: noted, edited question and text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print([(x // 2) == i for x in range(6)])
...
[True, True, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, True, True, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
k = 0
for i in range(3):
  # Other tasks
  myList = [False for x in range(4)]
  myList[k:k] = [True,True]
  print(myList)
  k += 2
```

Comment: Simpler: `for k in range(0, 6, 2)`

Comment: But @wjandrea i think the OP specifically wants to generate these inside the `range(3)` loop

Comment: @Wasif Sure, but `i` is not used, so it's pointless. As an alternative, you could do `k = i*2` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [False, False, False, False, True, True]

for _ in range(3):
    L = L[-2:] + L[:4]
    print(L)
```